# How do I get this self-signed cert into Node?

Tags: node.js, ssl, next.js, npx, pgtyped

In my nextjs project, I want to run npx [pgtyped](https://pgtyped.dev/), connecting to a digital ocean postgres instance. Digital ocean have thoughtfully provided me with a self-signed cert, which I put at the project root. The cert needs to be available to Node when I run `npx pgtyped`, but I can't seem to make this happen. The command in my package.json looks like this...

```
"pgtyped-watch": "cross-env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=\"./digital-ocean.crt\" npx pgtyped -w -c pgtyped-config.json"
```

...and gives this output...

```
PS C:\dev\my-proj> npm run pgtyped-watch

> my-proj@0.1.0 pgtyped-watch
> cross-env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="./digital-ocean.crt" npx pgtyped -w -c pgtyped-config.json

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12)
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}

Node.js v18.14.0
```

**npx is not getting the cert**. Is there some way I can break this down, to test the presence of the environment variable, or to see the details of the self-signed cert it's complaining about. (I only have one digital ocean postgres instance so I can't possibly have the wrong cert.)

For completeness, my pgtyped-config.json is...

````
{
  "transforms": [
    {
      "mode": "sql",
      "include": "**/*.sql",
      "emitTemplate": "{{dir}}/{{name}}.queries.ts"
    }
  ],
  "srcDir": "./src/",
  "failOnError": false,
  "camelCaseColumnNames": false,
  "db": {
    "host": "db-postgresql-ams3-myproj-do-user-14475298-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com",
    "port": 25060,
    "user": "doadmin",
    "dbName": "defaultdb",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ssl": true
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it**. The cert being self-signed, I need to set environment variables both to tell npx where to find it, *and* to accept self-signed. To do this, I needed to put npx before my calls to cross-env. Seems simple enough.

So the working command is...

```
"pgtyped-watch": "npx cross-env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=\"./digital-ocean.crt\"  npx cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0  npx pgtyped -w -c pgtyped-config.json"
```